# What's the term for a show which is augmented with content in real life?

Tags: terminology, social-media

For example the BBC's Sherlock series seeps into reality via [Dr John Watson's Blog](http://www.johnwatsonblog.co.uk/) and various characters' Twitter accounts.

I think it's something along the lines of *multi-format media*; but can't recall the exact term.

Comment: `Multichannel-media` seems promising (given `multichannel-marketting`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multichannel_marketing); but sadly doesn't seem to be a recognised term.

Comment: Few if any productions have no intersections with real-life phenomena.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth; agreed; all shows have interaction by way of an audience, marketing, merchandise, etc.  However I'm talking about scenarios where the story itself lapses beyond the screen into other forms of media (or even real life events)... not just marketing gimmicks, but as a way to create a more immersive experience than the episodes or movie alone could.

Comment: Ah, got it. 'What's the term for a production which is augmented with extensions of the fiction into other media, such as fictional blogs etc?'

Comment: I don't know the existing term for this, but the idea sounds like simulated something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calling it an *interactive TV show* that has elements of *TV synchronicity*.

> Load Testing an interactive TV Show with over 1 Million Users ...
>   One of the big technical challenges was the achievement of the so called "TV synchronicity": Enabling an interactive, real time game experience with the TV audience via the Quizduell App at home
>   [- Stormforger](https://stormforger.com/blog/2014/05/27/load-testing-an-interactive-tv-show-with-over-1-million-users/)

It's also been termed *social TV*:

> Real-time content synchronization between offline and online media has become the darling of social TV, frequently serving as its very definition for companies looking to marry traditional and digital marketing experiences.
>   [prophet.com](https://www.prophet.com/thinking/2014/01/social-tv-solving-for-synchronicity-in-an-on-demand-future/)